# Understanding processes in Java [linux]

Tags: java, process

I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04`.

To execute some logic I need to start a process in Java as

```
String[] commandLine;
String[] environment;
//...
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine, environment);
InputStream processInputStream = p.getInputStream(); //<---- ?
```

But since `JVM` and the process are different ones I need to understand how they actually communicate. And through what (channels, sockets tcp/udp, pipes, or something else).

How does they actually transfer data?

Comment: "_since JVM and the process are different ones I need to understand how they actually communicate_" this is too broad. What are you expecting ? What do you think will be different based on the OS ?

Comment: @AxelH What do u mean too broad? If a process asks some data from another process there need to be some inter-process communication. So which one? Socket? If so, which socket (TCP/UDP)?

Comment: This is indeed an excellent question; I don't believe many people understand the implications of that question yet... I myself took some time understanding it really. But in the meanwhile, have you had a look at `ProcessBuilder`'s `.inheritIO()` method?

Comment: Might I suggest to edit the question? I do have edit privileges myself but I prefer the OP do it. What about: "what are std{in,out,err} when you create a new process?"

Comment: The communication between the JVM and the process executed, I didn't get that part... I honnestly never thought about it as the JVM will hide this to be cross-platform and let you use the `Stream` the same way on every OS (to be confirmed, might be some exception ?).

Comment: Are you asking about `Process.getInputStream()` specifically? That method usually corresponds to the operating system construct that is exposed by the platform's C runtime as the `stdout` of the child process. On Linux or any POSIX-compliant system it will be a pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the javadoc it seems to be using pipes by default.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is a short test, I also have Ubuntu, although it's a 16.10, I think these will behave the same. The program I wrote:

```
public final class Test
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("yes");
        final Process p = pb.start();

        try (
            final InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
        ) {
            while (true)
                in.read();
        }
    }
}
```

Using `pstree -uplan`, I found that that the PID of the `yes` process was some number n and when I did:

```
ls -l /proc/n/fd
```

I got:

```
lr-x------ 1 fge fge 64 May 29 15:52 0 -> pipe:[1482898]
l-wx------ 1 fge fge 64 May 29 15:52 1 -> pipe:[1482899]
l-wx------ 1 fge fge 64 May 29 15:52 2 -> pipe:[1482900]
```

which makes me say that the I/O exchange is done using anonymous pipes.